# mysql "groupconcat" with "if" condition in "where"

Tags: mysql, if-statement, group-concat

I need to find a solution where I can use the IF condition with "groupconcat"

```
select 
GROUP_CONCAT(
 DISTINCT bug_id) 
 from bugs 
 where sum( 
  IF((timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:02:00") && (priority="P1") ,1,0))) 
as bugids
```

It is throwing error.

ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

Note:- This select query is used as an inner query.

Any solution for getting the result bug ids using groupcontact and a where condition??

Comment: can you make a sql fiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT bug_id) from bugs where 
sum( IF((timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:02:00") && (priority="P1") ,1,0))
```

Comment: ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

Comment: select GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT bug_id) from bugs where sum( IF((timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:02:00") && (priority="P1") ,1,0)) and bugs.creation_ts <= '2013-06-16 08:59:59' and bug_status="RESOLVED";

but error:(

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer.

```
select 
GROUP_CONCAT( 
 DISTINCT bug_id) 
 from bugs 
 where  ( 
 IF(
 (timediff(delta_ts,creation_ts) > "00:02:00") && (priority="P1") 
 && (product_id=237)
 &&(bugs.resolution='FIXED')
 &&(bug_status="RESOLVED")
 &&(bugs.creation_ts >='2013-06-14 09:00:00' 
 and bugs.creation_ts <= '2013-06-16 08:59:59') ,1,0)) ;
```

```
+--------------------------------+
| GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT bug_id) |
+--------------------------------+
| 3743304                        |
+--------------------------------+
1 row in set, 65535 warnings (5.86 sec)
```